# How to generate multi-word search suggestions

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

I'm using Elasticsearch to build a small search app and am trying to figure out how to build an autocomplete feature with multi-word (phrase) suggestions. I have it working... sort of...

I get mostly single word suggestions, but when I hit the space bar - it kills the suggestions.

For example, if I type "fast" it works fine, if I type "fast " - that stops the suggestions from appearing.

I'm using `Edge N Grams` and `match_phrase_prefix` and have followed the examples [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html) and [here](https://qbox.io/blog/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams) to build it out. For the `_all` field in `match_phrase_prefix` and just used include_in_all: false to cancel all the fields out except for title and content. I'm starting to think its just because I'm testing on a small data set and there simply aren't enough tokenized terms to produce multi-word suggestions. Please take a look at the relevant code below and advise me where I'm going wrong, if any?

```
"analysis": {
"filter": {
 "autocomplete_filter": {
  "type": "edge_ngram",
  "min_gram": "1",
  "max_gram": "20",
  "token_chars": [
    "letter",
    "digit"
  ]
 }
},
"analyzer": {
  "autocomplete": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
    "filter": [
       "lowercase",
       "asciifolding",
       "autocomplete_filter"
    ]     
  },
  "whitespace_analyzer": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
    "filter": [
      "lowercase",
      "asciifolding"
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `keyword` tokenizer

```
"autocomplete": {
    "type": "custom",
           "filter": [
       "lowercase",
       "asciifolding",
       "autocomplete_filter"
    ],
 "tokenizer": "keyword"     
  }
```

for reference 
[elasticsearch mapping tokenizer keyword to avoid splitting tokens and enable use of wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486037/elasticsearch-mapping-tokenizer-keyword-to-avoid-splitting-tokens-and-enable-use)

Since by default its standard anaylyzer that splits on spaces 
You can check your tokens like  `curl 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?pretty=1&analyzer=my_edge_ngram_analyzer' -d 'FC Schalke 04'` reference https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html