# elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'No handler for type [string] declared on field [texts]')

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch python api to create mappings, but it went some wrong:

```
es = Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")
request_body = {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    'mappings': {
        'examplecase': {
            'properties': {
                'tbl_id': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string'},
                'texts': {'index': 'analyzed', 'type': 'string'},
            }
        }
    }
}
es.indices.create(index='example_index', body=request_body)
```

it shows `elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'No handler for type [string] declared on field [texts]')`, and I find some solution that they say: use `text` instead of `string` in the field type, but it also went wrong: `elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'Failed to parse mapping [examplecase]: Could not convert [texts.index] to boolean'). The elasticsearch version is`elasticsearch-6.5.4`. How can I deal with it?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this

> 'index': 'analyzed' OR 'index': 'not_analyzed'

is an older elasticsearch version mapping and not needed.

All you need to do is use '**text**' for analyzed string fields and '**keyword**' for not_analyzed text fields, like this:

```
es = Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")
request_body = {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    'mappings': {
        'examplecase': {
            'properties': {
                'tbl_id': {'type': 'keyword'},
                'texts': {'type': 'text'},
            }
        }
    }
}
es.indices.create(index='example_index', body=request_body)
```

see reference in Elastic docs here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Answer (score -1):

See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html#mapping-index). The `index` setting in your mapping is incorrectly configured. It is a mapping parameter and can be set to true or false only. You cannot set this within the properties parameter.